# Select specific columns of a 'density' object in R

Tags: r

I need to pick out individual observations from a density object in R. This is related to a [prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400032/how-do-i-select-points-in-a-dataset-above-x-contour-of-a-density-map) except my data is formatted differently.

I begin with a matrix of gene expression values "b", where the columns represent 10 observations and rows represent expression levels for 1000 genes.

```
b = matrix(rexp(1000),ncol=10)
```

Next, I plot the densities with each observation as a separate line.

```
d = apply(b, 2, density, na.rm = TRUE)

plot(b, type="n", ylim=c(0,1))
for (i in 1:10) { lines( d[[i]] ) } 
abline(h=0.5)
```

How do I pick out the columns in 'b' whose densities are below the horizontal line at 'b[,1]=0.5'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the estimated density at a particular value, you can use `approx` along with the points from the density object. For example

```
yv <- sapply(d, function(d) {
    approx(d$x, d$y, .5)[["y"]]
})
yv
# [1] 0.7158584 0.5516512 0.7049119 0.6180026 ...
```

This will predict the xvalue at x=.5 for each of the densities 10. To see which ones are below the horizontal line, you can do

```
which(yv<.5)
# [1] 5    # (your results may differ due to the random input)
```

So we see only the 5th column meets the criteria.

Comment: ...and for those who want to color code the plots: 
    `color=rep(1,length(d)); color[which(yv<.5)]=2 ; plot(b, type="n", ylim=c(0,1)); for (i in 1:10) {lines( d[[i]], col=c("grey","red")[color[i]] }; abline(h=0.5)`